# get_term_by not working when in functions.php

Tags: custom-taxonomy, functions, terms

I have an odd issue with get_term_by(). It's working fine when I use it inside a template, but when I use it in functions.php it just returns false.

```
$term = get_term_by('slug', 'some-term', 'some-taxonomy');
var_dump($term);
```

Any explanation as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the actual code? There's a chance that there is something wrong with the values sent to the function.

Comment: This *is* the actual code, I've change the term names to something generic, however in my test I would just copy-paste the line from functions.php to header.php and it would just work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably happening because the taxonomy you're trying to query is registered yet.  Eg. The WordPress environment is loaded when a theme's functions.php file loads, but many plugins/themes/core functions don't register taxonomies until later.

Try hooking into `init` with a really high priority number and running the `get_term_by` function.  Like so:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'wpse27111_tester', 999 );
function wpse27111_tester()
{
    $term = get_term_by('slug', 'some-term', 'some-taxonomy');
    var_dump($term);
}
```

Comment: Works great! I was suspecting it was something of that nature, thanks for the tip!

Comment: TY so much!  Just spent an hour trying to figure out why post categories was working and my custom taxonomies weren't...  hooked to init and all is better.

Comment: Was stuck on this for hours. Definitely should always remember to wrap functions.php stuff in hooks to control the order of execution.